# Format number with default NumDigAfterDec and without rounding

Tags: vbscript

I am using in my sql server reports a simple vbscript command to format some numeric fields:

```
FormatNumber(value,,-1,0,-1)
```

Important for me is the second parameter *NumDigAfterDec* that is set to default, meaning
that "the computer's regional settings are used" (http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatnumber.asp). This is exactly what I prefer. But when the current number has more digits after decimal, it is rounded. In this case I would like to see all places.

e.g. for two places after decimal, I would like:

```
 0       0.00
90.7    90.70
 1.2345  1.2345   (instead of 1.23)
```

Is this possible without writing code in my reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a condition stating if length of decimal is greater than 2 places, then display full decimal number, else 2 decimal places?

A simple way to do this is:

```
Dim value : value = "100.54367"
Dim GetDecCount : GetDecCount = Len(Mid(Value, instr(value, ".")+1, len(value)))
if GetDecCount>2 then 
msgbox "This number exceeds the regional decimal points of 2, with a length of " & GetDecCount & " decimal points."
else
FormatNumber(value,,-1,0,-1)
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = ".\d{3,}$"

if re.Test(value) Then
  fnum = CStr(value)
Else
  fnum = FormatNumber(value, , -1, 0, -1)
End If
```